# how to integrate the mongodb with zend framework 2?

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework

i am new to zend framework2.I want to make db connection with mongodb.how can i globally configure and connect mongodb with zend framework2?I have configured both the ZF2 and mongodb on Ubuntu But when i run the project then the following error occurs.
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for odm_default.

I have properly read and followed instructions on stackoverflow about ZF2 and mongodb.

Regrads,
Toqeer

Comment: Are both installed? Have you tried reading the instructions? If you tell us what doesn't work it would be easier.

Comment: yes both are installed.i read the instructions and followed it during installations.when i complete it then a fetal errors.

Comment: Thanks for replying! At least now we know you have done something. It would be better if you could put the error here and show us what went wrong.

Comment: when i configured both the ZF2 and mongodb then the following error occurs. Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for odm_default

Comment: Please edit your question and add those details in. The font size is larger and comments may be hidden ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not mentioned explicitly in your question or in your tags (at least, as of this writing), your reference to `odm_default` suggests that you are using attempting to use [Doctrine ODM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/) with ZF2.

The [DoctrineMongoODMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule) is probably your easiest path forward.